# Non-overlapping sliding window for 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a non-overlapping sliding window for a 2D array for python.  My code works great for a small array, but when I scale it up to a 4552 x 4552 array with a 455 x 455 size window, I get the following error:  `ValueError: array is too big; 'arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize' is larger than the maximum possible size`.  Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np

def rolling_window(a, shape, writeable=False):  # rolling window for 2D array
    s = (a.shape[0] - shape[0] + 1,) + (a.shape[1] - shape[1] + 1,) + shape
    strides = a.strides + a.strides    
    allviews = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=s, strides=strides) 
    non_overlapping_views = allviews[0::2,0::3]
    return non_overlapping_views

a = np.array([[0,  1,  2,  3,   4,  5],
              [6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11],
              [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
              [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
              [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
              [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]], dtype=np.int)
shape = (3,3)
result = rolling_window(a, shape)
print result

[[[[ 0  1  2]
   [ 6  7  8]
   [12 13 14]]

  [[ 3  4  5]
   [ 9 10 11]
   [15 16 17]]]


 [[[12 13 14]
   [18 19 20]
   [24 25 26]]

  [[15 16 17]
   [21 22 23]
   [27 28 29]]]]
```

Comment: You might be looking for [`skimage.util.view_as_blocks()`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your problem is directly related to convolution/max pooling operations.

I recently wrote naive approaches to those operations using only numpy, so I adapted one of them to (hopefully) answer your question.

Here is the code:

```
def rolling_window(input_array, size_kernel, stride, print_dims = True):
    """Function to get rolling windows.

    Arguments:
        input_array {numpy.array} -- Input, by default it only works with depth equals to 1. 
                                      It will be treated as a (height, width) image. If the input have (height, width, channel) 
                                      dimensions, it will be rescaled to two-dimension (height, width)
        size_kernel {int} -- size of kernel to be applied. Usually 3,5,7. It means that a kernel of (size_kernel, size_kernel) will be applied
                             to the image.
        stride {int or tuple} -- horizontal and vertical displacement

    Keyword Arguments:
        print_dims {bool} -- [description] (default: {True})

    Returns:
        [list] -- A list with the resulting numpy.arrays 
    """   
    # Check right input dimension
    assert(len(input_array.shape) in set([1,2])), "input_array must have dimension 2 or 3. Yours have dimension {}".format(len(input_array))

    if input_array.shape == 3:
        input_array = input_array[:,:,0]

    # Stride: horizontal and vertical displacement
    if isinstance(stride,int):
        sh, sw = stride, stride
    elif isinstance(stride,tuple):
        sh, sw = stride

    # Input dimension (height, width)
    n_ah, n_aw = input_array.shape

    # Filter dimension (or window)
    n_k  = size_kernel

    dim_out_h = int(np.floor( (n_ah - n_k) / sh + 1 ))
    dim_out_w = int(np.floor( (n_aw - n_k) / sw + 1 ))

    # List to save output arrays
    list_tensor = []

    # Initialize row position
    start_row = 0
    for i in range(dim_out_h):
        start_col = 0
        for j in range(dim_out_w):

            # Get one window
            sub_array = input_array[start_row:(start_row+n_k), start_col:(start_col+n_k)]

            # Append sub_array
            list_tensor.append(sub_array)
            start_col += sw
        start_row += sh

    if print_dims: 
        print("- Input tensor dimensions -- ", input_array.shape)
        print("- Kernel dimensions -- ", (n_k, n_k))
        print("- Stride (h,w) -- ", (sh, sw))
        print("- Total windows -- ", len(list_tensor))

    return list_tensor
```

To get non-overlapping rolling windows, you just need to set `stride` and `kernel_size` to the same number. Also, this will print some info, and the length of the windows found.

Some examples:

1) Yours:

```
a = np.array([[0,  1,  2,  3,   4,  5],
              [6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11],
              [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
              [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
              [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
              [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]], dtype=np.int)

size_kernel = 3 # Or can be set to 3 instead of a tuple
list_tensor = rolling_window(a, size_kernel, stride=3, print_dims = True)

##Output
#- Input tensor dimensions --  (6, 6)
#- Kernel dimensions --  (3, 3)
#- Stride (h,w) --  (3, 3)
#- Total windows --  4

for array in list_array:
    print('\n')
    print(array)

## Output
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [12 13 14]]


[[ 3  4  5]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [15 16 17]]


[[18 19 20]
 [24 25 26]
 [30 31 32]]


[[21 22 23]
 [27 28 29]
 [33 34 35]]
```

(Also, comparing with your results, I notice that your code gives you overlapping data, you can compare the second and fourth outputs.)

2) a (5000,5000) array with window (500,500)

```
%%time
size = 5000
a = np.ones((size,size))
list_tensor = rolling_window(input_array = a, size_kernel = 500, stride=500, print_dims = True)

## Output
#- Input tensor dimensions --  (5000, 5000)
#- Kernel dimensions --  (500, 500)
#- Stride (h,w) --  (500, 500)
#- Total windows --  100
#CPU times: user 68.7 ms, sys: 115 ms, total: 184 ms
#Wall time: 269 ms
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This helped a lot - thank you!  I had to change "return list_array" to "return list_tensor" and "for array in list_array:" to "for array in list_tensor:" and for my purposes I deleted

Comment: # Check right input dimension
    assert(len(input_array.shape) in set([1,2])), "input_array must have dimension 2 or 3. Yours have dimension {}".format(len(input_tensor))

    if input_array.shape == 3:
        input_array = input_array[:,:,0]

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful! and thanks for the observations, I will fix them :D